# Function to get messages inserted into db 5 mins ago

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ok so when i send a message it inserts message into a database.
a few mins later a webhook runs and inserts the same message into db

I only want to insert one message so im wrting code like this

```
$response = $this->messages_model->search_messages_five_mins_ago($recivernum,$msg);

if(!$response) {
    $newId = $this->Customer_m->insert_emaildata($add_email);
};
```

but have a problem creating function. so far i have this

```
public function search_messages_five_mins_ago($number,$msg)
{
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('messages');
$this->db->where('receiver_num',$number);   
$this->db->where('content',$msg);
// and created_at betteen now() -10 mins and now 
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
}
```

I dont want to insert message again if it was inserted within the last 10 mins

any ideas please and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple PHP to the rescue, all you need is `date` and `strtotime` to determine what "10 minutes ago" is.

Also, I'd suggest a better way to determine if something's been found by the query:

```
public function search_messages_five_mins_ago($number,$msg)
{
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('messages');
$this->db->where('receiver_num',$number);   
$this->db->where('content',$msg);
$this->db->where('created_at >=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('Y-m-d H:i:s'."-10 minute")));

$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
{
    // nothing found. You can do whatever you'd normally do
    return false;
}

else
{
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

This will find matching messages created after "now minus 10 minutes". Return false if nothing is found or return the message(s) if  found.

In your controller, I'd use

```
if($response == false) {
    $newId = $this->Customer_m->insert_emaildata($add_email);
};
```

Comment: Worked like a charm thank you very much Javier Larroulet